# Longer render distances in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to increase the maximum horizon render distance in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8711/is-there-a-way-to-increase-the-maximum-horizon-render-distance-in-minecraft)

Is there some way I can increase the render distance in minecraft? I have the fog at maximum distance, but when I am at the top of the mountains, that just is not far enough. I can only see the blue haze. Any settings I can change? Is there some mod that would help me? I would prefer it to work on smp.

Comment: That would hopefully teach me to search before posting better.

Comment: Though... The given answer on that thread is still quite lacking. It gives a link, but the link itself is not very good.

Comment: Re-asking the same question is not the right way to go about getting better answers. You could always offer a bounty.

Answer (score -1):

Since you didn't like the answer 'Mod your game'.

Then... no.

If you'd like to know how to mod your game, that's a different question entirely.

Comment: No, I am fine with moding the game, the answer is just not good enough. The tutorial is incomplete, and since it has been written the game has been updated, and with it, the obusification has changed.

Comment: Your question is not 'how do I mod the game'. Your question has been answered. The answer is 'no'.